# Azure subscription tied to a directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a MSDN subscription from my work account, when I login, I can see there is already an azure active directory associated (which is company's one I have read only access). I need to provision another AAD directory for development purpose, however when I 'switch' the directory I can see it has no Azure subscription, which I need the credit for.

Question, how to change this behavior, I am thinking either a) change the default directory for my msdn subscription or b) transfer the subscription over to the new directory?

Please help!

Comment: Do you need a new Azure Subscription or do you want users in the new Azure AD to have access to the existing Azure Subscription?

Comment: I want the users/application in the new Azure AD to have access to the resources existing subscription

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the current implementation, an Azure Subscription only trusts users from a single Azure AD.

From [`How Azure subscriptions are associated with Azure Active Directory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory):

> Every Azure subscription has a trust relationship with an Azure AD
>   instance. This means that it trusts that directory to authenticate
>   users, services, and devices. Multiple subscriptions can trust the
>   same directory, **but a subscription trusts only one directory**. You can
>   see which directory is trusted by your subscription under the Settings
>   tab. You can edit the subscription settings to change which directory
>   it trusts.

To answer your questions specifically, please see this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-understanding-resource-access) on how you can change the trust relationship between an Azure AD and an Azure Subscription.